# Windows Server 2008 - Remote Desktop 3389 - How to BLOCK Incoming PROXY

Tags: windows, networking, blocking

I'm managing a Server 2008. I need to access it by Remote Desktop on 3389.

But I'm experiencing several Brute-Force attacks on 3389 per day.

I notice that it always comes from the same workstation, but with different IPS.
I then assume that the hacker is using a proxy.

My question:
Is there a way to block Proxy incoming connections for 3389 on the firewall or elsewhere?

Thanks,
Zoe

Comment: Can you not white list the IPs / subnet that you are connecting from?

Comment: Yes, of course I can do that, but it's a hard work regarding the fact, that I need to access this server from different places(no proxies) in various countries.

Isn't there a simple way to detect incoming connections from proxy IP's and Block them ?

Comment: sounds like a good reason to use a VPN. Set up some kind of VPN at the server and use the firewall to only allow remote connections from the VPN server IP.

Comment: I can't think of any way you could possibly detect if an IP is being used as a proxy or not. If you are being hacked, you can't even be sure the hacker *is* using a proxy. What's to say he/she doesn't have control of hundreds of compromised machines from which the attacks are being directly launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block all connection from outside of your network and create a vpn in case you need to access it from different places.